# How do i Replace the GreenScreen Image in Kinect Plug in to a Texture2D that i want to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I could not replace the green screen to a background image that i want to.

i've tried working with the Shaders but nothing is changing as i wanted to. Other materials are not working also. i tried duplicating a material to overlay it and it would not work.

[image: enter your image description here]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, what am i missing?